# How to parse the flag value from a LINUX command string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, command-line

I am using an http/scheduler, and the only way for me to get the specific of these tasks is reading an string that look just like this

```
let str = "go run tasks/action/main.go --channel=2 --state=true --username=scheduler "


let channel = ?
let state= ?
```

Comment: Care to elaborate more on your issue? Like what errors you getting, what is the expected output.

Comment: @SamuelToh Nevermind, I got it. `channel = str.split("--channel")[1].split(" ")[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more reliable approach would be to solve this using regular expression. As you can guarantee it to work even when `state` and `channel` option is being specified the other way around.

I am no regular expression expert , so I will be very happy if someone can recommend me a better regexr.

**Approach:**

```
let str = "go run tasks/action/main.go --channel=211 --state=true --username=scheduler ";

let channel = /--channel=(.+?)\s/.exec(str)[1];
let state= /--state=(.+?)\s/.exec(str)[1];
```

Note that I am anchoring based on the idea that there will be a space `\s` behind each `option.value`, I think this will work in OP's use case but will not if 1 of the `option.value` has no space behind it. E.g. `"go run blah --state=true"`

Basically what I go there is to tell Regexr "Hey go look for `--channel=` string and capture all the characters after it until you see the next space (non-greedy)".

**Assumption:**
I also made an assumption that there will always be something to capture for option `channel` and `state`. You will get array `index out of bound` if the regexr captures nothing. To be safe, probably add a guard statement to make sure it matches something.